spl-token causing typescript issue
I'm running into a problem calling @solana/spl-token createMint from my anchor tests. When I remove the code for createMint below the test runs successfully without any issues, but once I uncomment I get the following issue:
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/steve/Development/solana/my-program/tests/my-program.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)

Here is my test code in full:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { MyProgram } from "../target/types/my-program";
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  createMint,
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("myprogram", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const payer = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = new Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899", "confirmed");

  const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  console.log(mintKeypair);

  console.log(payer.publicKey);

  const program = anchor.workspace.MyProgram as Program<MyProgram>;

  async function createMintToken() {
    await createMint(
      connection,
      payer.payer,
      payer.publicKey,
      payer.publicKey,
      9,
      mintKeypair
    );
  }

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
     console.log("working");
  });
});

As mentioned above if you remove the code for the createMint() call the tests run with no issue.
Lastly here's my package.json for versions:
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint:fix": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" -w",
    "lint": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" --check"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.28.0",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.93.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}

Thanks for any guidance.

same exact issue. let me know if you find a fix
im going to downgrade my node version to see if the new updates screwed with how TS/mocha works.
edit: didnt work
i fixed it by changing
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6"
to
"@solana/spl-token": "0.4.6"
it seems that 0.4.7 was causing the issue

downgrading @solana/spl-token to "0.4.6" from "0.4.7" worked. Thank you!
